# How to list all installed applications in to excel

Tags: windows, vba, excel, winapi

I'm using below code to list all software installed in to excel sheet

```
Sub ListAllSoftware()
    Application.Run (Clear)
    Dim StrComputer As String
    Dim objWMIService As Object
    Dim objSoftware As Object
    Dim objAllSoftwares As Object
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets("sheet1").Activate

    StrComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & StrComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set objAllSoftwares = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Product")

    'Start right below sheet headers.
    i = 2

    If objAllSoftwares.Count > 0 Then


        For Each objSoftware In objAllSoftwares
            With objSoftware
                Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = .Caption
                Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(i, 2).Value = .Version
            End With
            'Go to the next row.
            i = i + 1
        Next

        With Worksheets("sheet1")
            .Range("A:D").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
            .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
            .Range("A2").Select
        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        MsgBox "All applications from this computer were retrieved successfully!", vbInformation, "Done"

    Else

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        MsgBox "Unfortunatelly, applications from this computer could not be retrieved!", vbCritical, "Error"

    End If
End Sub


Sub Clear()
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        .Activate
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If LastRow > 1 Then
            .Range("A2:e" & LastRow).Clear
        End If
        .Columns("A:e").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Range("A2").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Problem is it's only returning some of the installed applications, not everything.  How do I get everything? For example, I have GPL Ghostscript installed and it does not come up in the list generated by this code.  I can see GPL Ghostscript in add remove (Programs and features in windows 7) control panel. Is there away to get the list from control panel in to excel?

Comment: Hi @Portland Runner thanks for the reply but i cant get version number from Win32_Directory i need to compare version numbers

Comment: I have changed this project from Excel VBA to Windows PowerShell script, read post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161524/how-to-run-execute-powershell-commands-in-excel-vba