# How to run / execute powershell commands in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, powershell, wmi-query

I’m writing some code to compare installed versions of software in some test computers currently I’m using a PowerShell PS1 script to create a text file and compare with previously created baseline text file

For the ease of end users I would like to automate these in a excel file, press a button and you get a result of what does not match with the baseline

My current ps1 scripts are

> :CreateDefaultApps.ps1 - Create the Default baseline DefApp32.txt or DefApp64.txt in My Documents folder

```
    cls
$CurDir = $myinvocation.InvocationName | split-path -parent
$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$TARGETDIR = "$DOCDIR\AppLog"
$COMPNAME = $env:computername
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR ))
{
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $TARGETDIR
}
cls
if ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    Write-Host "64bit Windows Detected"
    Write-Host "Collecting Product Information for"$COMPNAME
    If (Test-Path $TARGETDIR\DefApp64.txt)
    {
        Remove-Item $TARGETDIR\DefApp64.txt
    }
    Else
    {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version > $TARGETDIR\DefApp64.txt
    }
    write-host "File"$TARGETDIR"\DefApp64.txt Created"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "32bit Windows Detected"
    Write-Host "Collecting Product Information for"$COMPNAME
    If (Test-Path $TARGETDIR\DefApp32.txt)
    {
        Remove-Item $TARGETDIR\DefApp32.txt
    }
    Else
    {
        Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version > $TARGETDIR\DefApp32.txt
    }
    write-host "File " $TARGETDIR"\DefApp32.txt Created"
}
```

> :CompareApps.ps1 creates current list of applications and compare with Baseline

```
cls
$CurDir = $myinvocation.InvocationName | split-path -parent
Function Abort
{
Write-Host "Script Aborted"
}

$DOCDIR = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")
$TARGETDIR = "$DOCDIR\AppLog"
$COMPNAME = $env:computername
if(!(Test-Path -Path $TARGETDIR ))
{
    Write-Host $TARGETDIR" Folder does not Exist"
    Abort
}

Function Finish
{
write-host "Comparing Products Completed"
}

Function CreateCompNameFile
{
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name, Version > $TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME.txt
write-host "File"$TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME".txt Created"
}

Function Compare64
{
write-host "Comparing Products with file"$TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME".txt"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $TARGETDIR\DefApp64.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME.txt)
Finish
}

Function Compare32
{
write-host "Comparing Products with file"$TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME".txt"
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (Get-Content $TARGETDIR\DefApp32.txt) -DifferenceObject (Get-Content $TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME.txt)
Finish
}


cls
if ([environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    Write-Host "64bit Windows Detected"
    Write-Host "Collecting Product Information for"$COMPNAME
    If (Test-Path $TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME.txt)
    {
        Remove-Item $TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME.txt
        CreateCompNameFile
    }
    else
    {
        CreateCompNameFile
    }
    Compare64
}
else
{
    Write-Host "32bit Windows Detected"
    Write-Host "Collecting Product Information for"$COMPNAME
    If (Test-Path $TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME.txt)
    {
        Remove-Item $TARGETDIR\$COMPNAME.txt
        CreateCompNameFile
    }
    else
    {
        CreateCompNameFile
    }
    Compare32
}
```

I would prefer to run this code via excel and capture the list in a worksheet, then compare the baseline which is already in the worksheet. How do I execute or use commands from PowerShell in VBA?

Previously I have used (see post [How to list all installed applications in to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097726/how-to-list-all-installed-applications-in-to-excel))

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & StrComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set objAllSoftwares = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Product")
```

For some reason it does not retrieve all the software installed (which you can see in Add/Remove Programs) e.g. 7-Zip (64 bit), GPL Ghost Script to name a few
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Dumidu

Comment: Do it the other way around. Run your PowerShell scripts with the Excel file as a "database" from within the scripts (use it as an ODBC data source to read/write data to it).

Comment: Hi @alroc thanks for your reply, i have some other code in the excel file that i need to have, unless i can append to a excel file , i don't want to create new excel file.